# Why is there a superscript esf in Zap Chance font?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, truetype

I have a following sample html file in which I have included Zap Chance font.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style> 
                @font-face {
                font-family: myFirstFont;
                src: url(newfonts/ZapChance.ttf);
                }

                *{
                font-family: myFirstFont;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

[image: Output of html]

As I am using this font first time I am not sure what is this esf on top of every O letter.

Is this a normal behaviour of this font?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question but one about typography and fonts.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have an old, unpaid-for [shareware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shareware) font from a company called [Elfring Soft Fonts](https://www.elfring.com). In the 1990s, ESF was a popular source of cheap knockoffs of well-known fonts from the big, high-priced foundries.

Sellers of shareware fonts would often distribute free, crippled versions of the fonts, to allow people to try them out; the customer could then pay for the un-crippled version. The font crippling often consisted of omitting a certain letter, or in this case defacing a letter with the foundry's initials.

ESF seems to [still be selling this font](https://www.elfring.com/script.htm) using the name *Zen St Charles*. I assume the name *Zap Chance* was too similar to [*Zapf Chancery* (medium italic)](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/typefaces/story-of-zapf-chancery), the font that is being imitated.